# Problem with my Android application installation in SD Card?

Tags: android, android-manifest

In one of my application my customer reported the problem with installation. He/She is unable to install my application in his/her Android mobile it's having problem to install application in SD card how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you need to give some more information. What Android version is the customer using, is the customer using some mod ROM, is it just this one customer or are there more with that problem,... What kind of application is it, does it use Services?,....

Answer (score 1):

Is your customer's device running Android 2.2 or above? If not, then you cannot install to SD.

Have you specified `android:installLocation` in your manifest? If you do not, then by default, you can only install the app to internal memory regardless of Android version.

See [Android dev - manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) for general info, and [Android dev - installLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) for more detailed information on the `installLocation` tag including how to maintain backwards compatibility.